# Access a network drive in .NET 6 in AWS lambda

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm attempting to use an AWS lambda with .net 6 to connect to a network drive and download a file. I'm using the code from here https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-access-network-drive-using-c-sharp

```
public class ConnectToSharedFolder: IDisposable  
{  
    readonly string _networkName;  
  
    public ConnectToSharedFolder(string networkName, NetworkCredential credentials)  
    {  
        _networkName = networkName;  
  
        var netResource = new NetResource  
        {  
            Scope = ResourceScope.GlobalNetwork,  
            ResourceType = ResourceType.Disk,  
            DisplayType = ResourceDisplaytype.Share,  
            RemoteName = networkName  
        };  
  
        var userName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentials.Domain)  
            ? credentials.UserName  
            : string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", credentials.Domain, credentials.UserName);  
  
        var result = WNetAddConnection2(  
            netResource,  
            credentials.Password,  
            userName,  
            0);  
  
        if (result != 0)  
        {  
            throw new Win32Exception(result, "Error connecting to remote share");  
        }  
    }  
  
    ~ConnectToSharedFolder()  
    {  
        Dispose(false);  
    }  
  
    public void Dispose()  
    {  
        Dispose(true);  
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);  
    }  
  
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)  
    {  
        WNetCancelConnection2(_networkName, 0, true);  
    }  
  
    [DllImport("mpr.dll")]  
    private static extern int WNetAddConnection2(NetResource netResource,  
        string password, string username, int flags);  
  
    [DllImport("mpr.dll")]  
    private static extern int WNetCancelConnection2(string name, int flags,  
        bool force);  
  
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]  
    public class NetResource  
    {  
        public ResourceScope Scope;  
        public ResourceType ResourceType;  
        public ResourceDisplaytype DisplayType;  
        public int Usage;  
        public string LocalName;  
        public string RemoteName;  
        public string Comment;  
        public string Provider;  
    }  
  
    public enum ResourceScope : int  
    {  
        Connected = 1,  
        GlobalNetwork,  
        Remembered,  
        Recent,  
        Context  
    };  
  
    public enum ResourceType : int  
    {  
        Any = 0,  
        Disk = 1,  
        Print = 2,  
        Reserved = 8,  
    }  
  
    public enum ResourceDisplaytype : int  
    {  
        Generic = 0x0,  
        Domain = 0x01,  
        Server = 0x02,  
        Share = 0x03,  
        File = 0x04,  
        Group = 0x05,  
        Network = 0x06,  
        Root = 0x07,  
        Shareadmin = 0x08,  
        Directory = 0x09,  
        Tree = 0x0a,  
        Ndscontainer = 0x0b  
    }  
}
```

which works just fine when I'm running the lambda locally.  However, when I run it in the cloud, I'm getting an error:

> "errorType": "DllNotFoundException",
> "errorMessage": "Unable to load shared library 'mpr.dll' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libmpr.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory",

It can't find the "mpr.dll" file, which makes sense since it's a windows file. I was wondering if anyone had suggestions how to get around this, or if there was an easier way to connect to a network drive via lambda? I was looking at creating a container and running it https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html but I've never done that before and I"m not sure if it will solve my issue.

I also attempted to just include the "mpr.dll" file in the root of my project, but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: Sounds like a Windows dependency and AWS lambda runs on Linux. Have you considered using S3 storage?

Comment: Yes.  My last resort if I can't figure this out is to create a scheduled task to run that will get the file from the network drive and upload it to s3 so the lambda can take it from there, but would rather not have to do that.

Comment: You want a cloud hosted program to connect to your office network CIFS share? ...

Comment: Where is the "network drive"? Is it on your own network, or in the cloud?  What service/system is it running on?

Comment: The network drive is a Windows EC2 instance. The lambda is set up to run in a VPC and should have no issue with access to the instance. It's just a matter of downloading the file